# Kafka streams state store for what?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

As I got right from book, Kafka Streams state store it is a memory key/value storage to store data to Kafka or after filtering.

I am confused by some theoretical questions.

1. What is differenct Kafka streams state from another memory storage like Redis etc?
2. What is real case to use state storage in Kafka Streams?
3. Why topic is not alternative for state storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why topic is not alternative for state storage?

A topic contains messages in a sequential order that typically represents a log.

Sometimes, we would want to aggregate these messages, group them and perform an operation, like *sum, for example* and store it in a place which we can retrieve later using a *key*. In this case, an ideal solution would be to use a key-value store rather than a topic that is a log-structure.

> What is real case to use state storage in Kafka Streams?

A simple use-case would be [word count](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.4.1-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaExample.java) where we have a word and a counter of how many times it has occurred. You can see more examples at [kafka-streams-examples on github](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples#examples-apps).

> What is difference between Kafka streams state from another memory storage like Redis etc?

State can be considered as a *savepoint* from where you can resume your data processing or it might also contain some useful information needed for further processing (like the previous word count which we need to increment), so it can be stored using *Redis*, *RocksDB*, *Postgres* etc.

Redis can be a *plugin* for Kafka streams state storage, however the default persistent state storage for Kafka streams is *RocksDB*.

Therefore, Redis is not an alternative to Kafka streams state but an alternative to Kafka streams' default *RocksDB*.

Answer (score 1):

-Why topic is not alternative for state storage?

Topic **is** the final statestore storage under the hood (everything is topic in kafka)

If you create a microservice with name "myStream" and a statestore named "MyState", you'll see appear a myStream-MyState-changelog with has an history of all changes in the statestore.

RocksDB is only the local cache to improve performances, with a first layer of local backup on the local disk, but at the end the real high availability and exactly-once processing guarantee is provided by the underlying changelog topic.

- What is differenct Kafka streams state from another memory storage like Redis etc?
- What is real case to use state storage in Kafka Streams?

It not a storage, it's a just local, efficient, guaranteed memory state to manage some business case is a fully streamed way.
As an example :

For each Incoming Order (Topic1), i want to find any previous order (Topic2) to the same location in the last 6 hours

Answer (score 0):

I am aligned with the approach of @sid. Kafka Streams State Store can be used as a Cache through Kafka Streams Interactive Query.

You can access the values stored in the state store using the corresponding Key through the Kafka Streams Intaractive Query interface.

When you use this, you can make Queries to the state table stored in the state store directly from an external application, such as a microservice via REST or GRPC. This allows you to quickly access the data stored without having to make direct queries to the Kafka Topics.

For example using code to  perform query using Interactive Query:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,"statestore-example");
prop.put(StreamsConfig.BOOSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");

StreamBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

KTable<String, Product> exampleTable = builder.table("topic-example");
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
streams.start();
```

Then, in your external application, you can use Kafka Streams Interactive Query to access the Example Data:

```
StreamsConfig streamsConfig = new StreamsConfig(props);
KafkaStreamsStateStoreProvider stateStoreProvider = new KafkaStreamsStateStoreProvider(streamsConfig);
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Example> exampleStore = stateStoreProvider.getQueryableStore("example-store", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());

String exampleId = "12345";
Example example = exampleStore.get(exampleId);

if (example != null) {
    // Process the found example
} else {
    // The example does not exist in the state table
}
```

In this example, "topic-example" is the kafka topic used to build the Example state store table in Kafka streams application.Then, in the external app, we use Interactive Query to access the table an retrieve the specifc Example using its ID as the lookup key.

I hope what has been said is useful.